# How can I edit a huge SQL-dump?

Tags: php, sql, regex, edit, mysql

I have a huge SQL-Dump with a lot of statements like

```
CREATE TABLE ...
INSERT INTO ...
```

and so on.

I want to edit this file. At first I want to delete all "CREATE TABLE" statements with all attributes. I only want the "INSERT INTO" statements. Is there an easy way? I'm a rookie at this area.

All "INSERT INTO" statements look like this:

```
INSERT INTO 'xyz' VALUES (a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h), (c,d,e,g) ...
```

I want to have it this way at the end:

```
INSERT INTO 'xyz' VALUES (<tenant_id>, a, b, c, d), (<tenant_id>, e, f, g, h), ...
```

Is there an easy way to realize that? E.g. with PHP or Regex? And how can I do this? 
Thank you!

Comment: `<tenant_id>` - what is it?

Comment: its just a placeholder/dummy. if the dump includes this in the values, i can fill it afterwards. i just want to insert something, a variable or anything else.

Comment: I do not see your origin problem. But why you cannot import your dump , add new field to your ables and create new dump with data only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have access any unix like system I recommend this:

```
sed '/CREATE TABLE */d' current.dump > new.dump
```

it will remove all the create table lines and pipe the rest to a new dump file

Comment: This can also be done on Windows machines. Just download SED for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

See example 10 "display the lines which does not matches all the given pattern" from http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/

```
Syntax:
grep -v -e "pattern" -e "pattern"
```

e..g.

```
grep -v -e "CREATE TABLE" current.dump > new.dump
```

The assumption is that the CREATE TABLE statement is on a single line.

For Windows you could use various ports of grep command, e.g. http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html

http://www.wingrep.com/

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm